# Enumerating Documents in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I'm working on some C# code that performs tasks based on certain documents.  Currently, I'm using `Document[] releaseDocs = Document.GetRootDocuments()` and then looping through the results.

Is it possible to do something like `Document[] releaseDocs = Document.GetRootDocuments().Where(m => m.Published == false);` where I could take advantage of the API to only get Published Documents and Documents with certain set Variables?  If so, how, because that method doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Document[] documents = Document.GetRootDocuments();

foreach (var doc in documents)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine:

```
Document[] releaseDocs = Document.GetRootDocuments().Where(m =>
    m.Published == false &&
    m.getProperty("SomeAlias").Value.Equals("Some Value")).ToArray();
```